# popViewController not working in NSURLSessionDataTask block in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, popviewcontroller

I have created request and I want to popView when i will get success message in response. Here is my code :

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSString *baseURLRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/email_addr=%@",mySession.baseURL,self.txtEmail.text];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLRequest] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *dict = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSString *msg = [dict objectForKey:@"msg"];

        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"])
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self showMesssgeonAlert:@"Success"];
                [self hideProgress];

                [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            });
        }
        else
        {
        }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Below isn't working,

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? `UINavigation controller` is also same for both the `viewControllers`. Please help me,Thanks.

Comment: check if ([[dict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"]) success and check if self.navigationcontroller is non nil

Comment: Check `self.navigationController` is nil or not

Comment: if [self showMesssgeonAlert:@"Success"]; and   [self hideProgress]; methods are called kindly check your navigationController might be nil. Have u embededed navigation controller in storyboard.???

Comment: @vinoth [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; this must be removed from last line

Comment: Yeah it's my mistake, I have fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: self.navigationController is not nil also i have embeded navigation controller in storyboard.

Answer (score -2):

@DevTest you can not put [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; inside dispath queue,  queue will not pop viewcontroller so, you will set out side dispatch queue...

Comment: It's inside a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`, which is correct.